# Why Google hides important and useful features?

Tags: google

## Background

Here's an excerpt from fastcodesign **[interview](http://worrydream.com/fastco_2011-10-06/)** with Bret Victor:

> QUESTION: An argument I'm going to make is that **UIs should ideally be "deep"**
>   -- that is, simple, intuitive and error-tolerant on the surface, but with levels of more "surgical" functionality built-in below for users
>   **to discover and exploit as they grow more skilled** with the software.
>
> ANSWER: A lot of designers would say they strive for that, yes.  But I don't
>   like that as an ideal at all.  For me, **the ideal UI offers many uses
>   for many people, but accomplishes that without hidden "deep" features.**
>   A piece of paper, for example, can be used for all sorts of things --
>   pictures, poetry, airplanes, spitballs, stabilizing a wobbly table --
>   but it doesn't offer those as "hidden features".  It's just flexible.

In short, Bret is against hiding features based on user's expertise.

## Example

Google limits the power of casual users by presenting only a text box
and some filtering options. If you a are power user, and you need more control over your search, you should discover by yourself the advanced features of Google buried in some page somewhere in the internet.

These advanced features or **hidden commands** include:

- `"search term"` only show exact matches
- `~search` use synonyms of "search".
- `-search` exclude results with the word search.

These are *extremely* useful options and Google hides them all from the general searcher.

### Google's doing it for simplicity's sake!

Yes, but in doing so, Google is dividing its user base into: dumbass and smartass OR more formally, casual and power user. Also, it's cheating a part of its users by hiding features (or making them hard to access). As we read in the interview, Bret Victor thinks that's bad. So what's good then?

### Bret's Solution

Basically, Bret has made the advanced features discoverable yet unobtrusive.
Below is the image.

[image: Solution]

## My view

At the moment, I must agree with Bret Victor's philosophy:

1. **Avoid dividing** users and functionality based on expertise.
2. **Avoid hiding** features but make them easily discoverable yet unobtrusive.

As I understand, ignoring above rules will always disappoint one of the two groups and I don't like that. On the other hand, I wonder whether it is possible to make all important features discoverable yet unobrtusive.

## My question

Has there been any research on these two competing philosophies? Are there any reasons to prefer one to the other?

Comment: Apple has a long history of this as well in their UI design...and is arguably a basic tenet of theirs. I don't agree that this divides users at all and, in fact, would argue the opposite...it's an all-inclusive concept where everyone is brought in at the same level and everyone is enabled to find their own level of feature depth. (And while this is a fascinating topic, asking "which is most effective" isn't a great question for StackExchange. It's perhaps a bit too broad. Maybe you can narrow the question down a bit?)

Comment: Bret's main point is that all humans CAN learn advanced stuff, if the system helps without confusing them. What Google and other designers are doing is taking an anti-learning approach by discouraging discovery and learning for common users. And yes, I am ready to narrow my question down...please tell me how :)

Comment: Anyone can learn complex 'stuff', but not everyone wants a complex UI. This solution accommodates those that don't want it, with the advantage of advanced features for those that do.

Comment: @DA01 I think that approach accommodates all users rather clumsily. Users sometimes fail to understand what exactly that they want. They try buttons and controls presented to them, and they try (or research) no more, and fail to accomplish their task. In such cases who's at fault, the system or the user? I'd say the system is indirectly discouraging the users from making the best use of the system.

Comment: I guess Apple's and Google's earnings would disagree, but in the end, while it's a *very* interesting topic, it's debatable. And, alas, perhaps not ideal for StackExchange.

Comment: @DA01 OK. Would you please help me make the question alright for StackExchange? I don't see how I can reword the question.

Comment: You could maybe word it as 'has there been research on these two competing philosophies?'.

Comment: Physical electronic devices often have the same concept:  the less used controls are hidden under sliding panels or flaps.

Comment: @PhillipW In devices with small screens the "hidden" approach is essential. And they show advanced features under 'sliding panels or flaps' whereas Google has removed even the "advanced search" link from its homepage -- an indicator of taking the "hidden" approach -- which further increases the gap between power and casual users.

Comment: Google not only **hides** features but also **terminates** whole products and product lines. It "does no evil"...

Answer (score 3):

**1. People are different**
As [Internet World Stats says](http://www.internetworldstats.com/stats.htm), there are almost 2.5 billions of Internet users now. And even people in a same office or home are different, didn't you experience this? It shouldn't be ignored. UX adopts it and use many tools for it (Personas, etc.).

**2. Software products are different**
There is range from mass market software to narrowed niche software. Feature requirements and UI for them are formed with the help of UX techiques.

**3. No ideal solution**
Software is constantly changing and improving. UX provide some formalisation in doing it, but there are no absolute markers of the final perfect solution, just keep process.

**Bret's solution**
[image]
In Bret's solution only small part of Google advanced functionality is shown. Such way no ideal, besides discovered functionality, it has disadvantages. A user limited to available options but others are beyond his mind. So again, it is too simple. The circle closed...

Answer (score 1):

Very interesting question.. I think the issue is not with the "hiddenness" of a feature but aligning with the user's mental model.

In the paper example there is nothing that says that it can be folded, no one teaches us that either. It's justa  natural reaction. If one sees a button, there is a tendency to press it - many times even if one doesn't need to.

Looking at the google interface, I see it flexible like paper, however it's not evident that it's that flexible. In Apple mail client search, it suggests things as I type. So if I type a name, it suggests that I can search that in the Person Name field or in Subject field.

[image]

In other words, if the user typed whatever they naturally think in the search box and got exactly the result that they expected, then it's like paper.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, Alok. According to my understanding, Bret is comparing Paper's flexibility with an application's flexibility -- NOT paper with app. However, I think Bret's statement is ambiguous probably due to the nature of interviews. What I want is an objective comparison: deep (and hidden) vs flat (and discoverable) interfaces.